# Disable or remove permissions for Scald page display

Tags: 7, scald

It appears to me that Scald does not have a permission allowing you to set who can view the "page view" of the atom /atom/ATOMID.

Is there some way to restrict access to this page or revoke permissions from roles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a partial answer, simply blocks non-logged in visitors:

```
function MYMODULE_init() {
  // Prevent public users from seeing the atom pages
  global $user;
  if(arg(0) == 'atom' && !$user->uid) {
    drupal_not_found();
    exit;
  }
}
```

I would really like it if there was a permission on the scald module, logged an issue on d.o for that https://www.drupal.org/node/2512692.

**Edit**: there is a patch on that d.o issue which adds a permission to 'access atom page view', which is a better solution to the use of  hook_init() above.